# Проблемы с Socket'ом, connection multicast и TextMeshPro в пустом проекте Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

В Unity, даже в только что созданном проекте есть ряд ошибок:

**Socket: bind failed, error: Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа. (10013)**

**Unable to join player connection multicast group.**

**Assembly for Assembly Definition File 'Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro/Tests/Runtime/Unity.TextMeshPro.Tests.asmdef' will not be compiled, because it has no scripts associated with it.
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface:TickCompilationPipeline (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorScriptCompilationOptions,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget)**

Последнее - только при первом запуске созданного проекта.

Версия Unity - 2019.4.26f1 (64-bit)

С чем это связано и как исправить?

*P.S. Ответы которые находил, не помогают.*

Comment: как может быть ошибка в только созданном проэкте связанная с ассетом TextMeshPro если этот ассет не входит в сборку юнити по дефолту?

Comment: @Andrew, в этом то и дело

Comment: Представьте, что все вопросы, связанные с Юнити будут иметь заголовки: `Проблемы с Unity`,`Не работает Unity`,`Ошибка в Unity`... Понимаете, когда человек видит заголовок, который совершенно не раскрывает суть вопроса, велика вероятность, что этот человек вообще не кликнет по вашему вопросу и не обратит на него ни секунды своего внимания.

Comment: @МаксимФисман, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1280206/revisions